# Learning the list SKB is on

Tags: linux-kernel, network-programming, kernel-module

I want to use `void skb_unlink(struct sk_buff *skb, struct sk_buff_head *list)` but I do not know how can I get the `struct sk_buff_head *list` SKB is on?

Comment: Nope not possible. you should not just unlink skb from a queue even if you find that by traversing the list. Each driver maintains its own queue if required. so tweak a driver or some network module which deal with skb queues.

Comment: What you mean "tweak a driver or some network module"? Can you explain it? If I cannot use skb_unlink() why there is such a func! I am sorry for trivial questions, I try to understand the logic and learn the details.

Comment: cscope "skb_unlink" in linux kernel code. You will find the answer

Comment: "why there is such a func!"? "Each driver/network subsystem maintains its own queue if required" for example sockets.

Comment: OK. Lets say, there are two pc and first one pings to second one. I want to insert a module at the first one and block these ping requests. In other words, second pc will never see ping packets come from first pc. Is this possible?